# Binding models in ASP.NET MVC-5 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm beginer in ASP.NET MVC. I have a problem with models types in MVC controller.
Here is my controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAd(Guid id)
    {
        AdDTO ad =  await _userAdService.GetAdDTOAsync(UserId,id);
        return View(ad); 
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAd(RemoveUserAd command)
    {
        await DispatcheAsync<RemoveUserAd>(command);
        return RedirectToAction("AllAds","UserAd");
    }
```

Class 'AdDTO' has property 'Id', but 'RemoveUserAd' class has property named 'AdID'.

How can I pass AdDTO.Id to RemoveUserAd.AdId using mvc view? It is any way to bind models/properties in view in this section:

```
 <form asp-action="DeleteAd"> 
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id"  />
    <input type="submit" value="DeleteAd" class="btn btn-default" /> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</form>
```

View code:

```html
@model AdPortal.Infrastructure.DTO.AdDTO

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Ad</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Content)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddDate)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddDate)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpiryDate)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ExpiryDate)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
  <form asp-action="DeleteAd"> 
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id"  />
        <input type="submit" value="DeleteAd" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

AdDTO model

```
public class AdDTO
{
    public Guid Id{get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public DateTime AddDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime ExpiryDate {get; set;} 
    public string UserId {get; set;}
    public Guid UserName {get;set;}
}
```

RemoveUserAd command model

```
public class RemoveUserAd
{
    public Guid AdId {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something but aren't you already passing the id? Doesn't the id in DeleteAd(Guid id) belong to the ad that you want to delete? Please post both Models, the controller that returns the delete form, and the rest of the view that contains the form.

Comment: I'm passing AdDTO model to the  DeleteAd View.  I will edit the post to paste code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AdDTO` is supposed to be the view model, then on your `[HttpDelete]` action you don't take the `RemoveUserAd` model. Instead, you take `AdDTO` model back.

And then before you dispatch the command, you construct the command from the view model `AdDTO`, either manually or using `AutoMapper`.

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAd(AdDTO model)
{
    var command = new RemoveUserAd
    {
        AdId = model.Id,
        ....
    };

    await DispatcheAsync<RemoveUserAd>(command);
    return RedirectToAction("AllAds","UserAd");
}
```

### Side note

On your form, don't you need to specify `method="delete"`?

On your `Controller`, don't you need `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`? Or you have it enable globally `config.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());`?

---

### Feedback from comments

If you worry about `OverPosting`, then in the action you just take `Id` instead the whole `AdDTO` model.

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAd(Guid id)
{
    var command = new RemoveUserAd
    {
        AdId = id,
        ....
    };

    await DispatcheAsync<RemoveUserAd>(command);
    return RedirectToAction("AllAds","UserAd");
}
```

Comment: This is not required.  The model binder does not care what model was pushed down to the view.  As long as the properties exist and are named correctly, the model binder will bind them to whatever model you want.

Comment: True, that means `RemoveUserAd` either has to inherit from `AdDTO` OR has certain same properties defined in `AdDTO` class. But from the question this is not the case (at least `RemoveUserAd` doesn't sound to be inherited from `AdDTO` to me).

Comment: It doesn't have to inherit from anything.  As long as it has the same properties.  This is advantageous because the model can actually represent only the values you actually need and can be a big benefit to prevent [OverPosting](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Comment: I understand but in this problem the properties @michals is trying to bind are not the same between those 2 models: `AdDto.Id` vs `RemoveUserAd.AdId`. And I understand what OverPosting is, but in this problem IMO it doesn't matter because the command is built manually. He's not taking the `AdDTO` model directly into the next processes. Again, the solution I provide is for this problem. I wouldn't build it this way myself.

Comment: No worries, I worry about other users who read statements like *If AdDTO is supposed to be the view model, then on your [HttpDelete] action you don't take the RemoveUserAd model. Instead, you take AdDTO model back.* and they assume that has to always be the case without a second thought :(  Your solution is completely valid, I would purpose that changing the property name is IMHO a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for help. I decided to use AutoMapper and Map DTO to Command. Of course [HttpDelete] attribute does not work it should be [HttpPost] in that situation.